# Selector for when child of brother is present

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of HTML.

```
<div class="page-top">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h2></h2>
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page-controls buttons">
        <a href="" class="button"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

With two different styles for the `h1`. One where I apply a `padding-top` to the `h1` when it's show alone. And the other style, for when the `h1` is preceded by an `h2`, I remove the `padding-top` with `.page-title h2 + h1`

My question is how would you select the `page-controls.buttons`, only when the `h1` is preceded by the `h2`. Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't select previous siblings with CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector

Comment: `Is it possible?` Using JavaScript, yes it is.

Comment: `h1` *should* come before an `h2`. How are you controlling when the `h2` is or is not shown?

Comment: It is possible, but will require restructuring your markup.  If markup cannot be changed, then JS/jQuery is the way to go.

Comment: @DRD I can change the markup, that's not a problem. How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with restructured markup: http://jsfiddle.net/functionalcss/k8dzg5zm/.

HTML:

```
<div class="page-top">
    <h2>Smaller Heading</h2>
    <h1>Big Heading</h1>
    <div class="page-controls buttons">
        <a href="" class="button">Click me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-top > h2 +  h1 + .page-controls.buttons {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked. Although I decided to give position absolute to one of the elements and accomplish what I needed.